# Python permutations skipping duplicates

Tags: python, permutation

My problem is: I have a list of values

```
model = ["AT","V","AP","RH"]
```

and I want to generate their permutations without duplicates.

A permutation in this case for me is e.g.

```
["AT"]
["V"]
["AP"]
["RH"]
["AT","V"]
["AT","AP"]
....
["AT","V","AP"]
["AT","V","RH"]
....
["AT","V","AP","RH"]
```

without duplicates in this case means, the order doesn't matter for me

```
["AT","V"] == ["V","AT"] is the same for me
```

```
["AT","V","AP","RH"] == ["RH","AT","V","AP"] == ["AP","RH","AT","V"] is the same for me
```

Any idea how I can reach my goal a smart way?

I found some solutions e.g. itertools.permutations but it didn't actually work for me as it doesn't consider my wish to ignore "duplicates"

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You are computing a powerset (minus the empty set), not permutations. A permutation of `model` is a list of the elements in a particularly order. (For example, `["V", "AT", "RH", "AP"]`, `["RH", "AP", "V", "AT"]`, etc. are all different permutations of the list `["AT", "V", "AP", "RH"]`.)

Comment: In permutations, order matters, hence the ‘duplicates’ are not duplicate.  However, with *combinations* order does not matter, so ‘duplicates’ will not be included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` with `itertools.combinations`. `itertools.combinations` will generate all combinations of a given size. To get all the desired combinations, we iterate over all possible sizes. Then, we use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, which will collect all of the combinations into one flattened iterable:

```py
list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(model, i) for i in range(1, len(model) + 1)))
```

This outputs:

```
[('AT',), ('V',), ('AP',), ('RH',),
...
('AT', 'AP', 'RH'), ('V', 'AP', 'RH'), ('AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH')]
```

Comment: FYI, this is basically the definition given for the `powerset()` function in the `itertools` documentation (adjusted to exclude the empty set).

Comment: Thank you, that's impressive. It works of course, but I guess I need some more minutes to understand what it actually does and figure it out in detail.

Comment: I added an explanation, let me know if you have any other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from more_itertools import powerset

list(powerset(["AT","V","AP","RH"]))

#[(),
 ('AT',),
 ('V',),
 ('AP',),
 ('RH',),
 ('AT', 'V'),
 ('AT', 'AP'),
 ('AT', 'RH'),
 ('V', 'AP'),
 ('V', 'RH'),
 ('AP', 'RH'),
 ('AT', 'V', 'AP'),
 ('AT', 'V', 'RH'),
 ('AT', 'AP', 'RH'),
 ('V', 'AP', 'RH'),
 ('AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH')]

[list(x) for x in powerset(["AT","V","AP","RH"])][1:]  # omitting the blank value

[['AT'],
 ['V'],
 ['AP'],
 ['RH'],
 ['AT', 'V'],
 ['AT', 'AP'],
 ['AT', 'RH'],
 ['V', 'AP'],
 ['V', 'RH'],
 ['AP', 'RH'],
 ['AT', 'V', 'AP'],
 ['AT', 'V', 'RH'],
 ['AT', 'AP', 'RH'],
 ['V', 'AP', 'RH'],
 ['AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH']]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `itertools.combinations` instead of `itertools.permutations`.

```
permutations(p[, r])
  r-length tuples, all possible orderings, no repeated elements

combinations(p, r)
  r-length tuples, in sorted order, no repeated elements
```

Here is an example:

```py
import itertools


def combos(elements):
    return [
        combo
        for i in range(len(elements))
        for combo in itertools.combinations(elements, i + 1)
    ]


model = ["AT", "V", "AP", "RH"]


combos(model)

# [('AT',),
#  ('V',),
#  ('AP',),
#  ('RH',),
#  ('AT', 'V'),
#  ('AT', 'AP'),
#  ('AT', 'RH'),
#  ('V', 'AP'),
#  ('V', 'RH'),
#  ('AP', 'RH'),
#  ('AT', 'V', 'AP'),
#  ('AT', 'V', 'RH'),
#  ('AT', 'AP', 'RH'),
#  ('V', 'AP', 'RH'),
#  ('AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH')]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations